# Javascript - Creating a print to HTML function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I am trying to create a "printf" function that will take in input 'x' and output the resulting data to print inside of a 'p' tag with an 'id' of 'para'. But I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I don't know if I should use 'this' in conjunction with 'x'. But I don't know.

Here's my JS:

```
function printf(x) {
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
};

printf("Hello!");
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="play">

    Input:<input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="check()">Submit</button>

    <div id="open">
        <h3>Terminal:</h3>

        <p id="para"></p>
    </div>

    <h1>Time to play a game!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your JS called from? It would need to be called after the browser has parsed your html. You don't need `this` for the function in question.

Comment: Your code should work fine. You tagged it with [syntax-error], what's the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

Here your working code. You have missed `return`.

```js
function printf(x) {
  return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
};

printf("Hello!");
```

```html
<div class="play">

  Input:
  <input type="text" id="userInput" />
  <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="check()">Submit</button>

  <div id="open">
    <h3>Terminal:</h3>

    <p id="para"></p>
  </div>

  <h1>Time to play a game!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would that function need a return statement when it directly updates the html element's content? You're just returning the same value that was passed into the function, and the line that calls the function doesn't try to use the returned value.

Comment: Tried the version without `return`, it works. So the problem may be that the user didn't call it